# Problems with installing web based Dashboard (DM Dashboard) with Git, MongoDB, Node, mean.io, Forever

Tags: mongodb, forever

I was trying to get the DM Dashboard working on my Ubuntu 16.04. You can find it here: https://github.com/dm-dashboard/dashboard

I already installed Git, MongoDB, Node, Mean.io and Forever. I'm new to working with all of the things, including Git. There are two things I don't understand:

1. In the instructions you can find this:

> ```
> Before we start the server, we will need to configure it for your environment
> ```
>
> To Configure
>
> ```
> Change to the checkout folder
> Open config/env/development.json
> Update the "db" property to point to your mongo DB
> Save and close the file
> ```

When opening the development.js the part where "db" is foud says:

```
module.exports = {
  db: 'mongodb://' + (process.env.DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR || 'localhost') + '/dashboard',
  debug: true,
  //  aggregate: 'whatever that is not false, because boolean false value turns aggregation off', //false
  aggregate: false,
  mongoose: {
    debug: false
},
```

Now what do I have to change to what? I don't know where my MongoDB is.

2. To open the Dashboard in a browser the instruction says:

> Open your browser and navigate to
>
> ```
> http://[path_to_where_you_deployed]:3000
> ```

What does "path_where_you_deployed" mean?

I feel like the solution is very simple, but I just can't figure out what to do.

I really appreciate you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db` should be your Mongo DB URI

`[path_to_where_you_deployed]` will we where you spin up this server, such as 127.0.0.1 if you're running locally for dev... or a heroku url if you deploy there

Comment: Where can I find my Mongo DB URI? I've just downloaded MongoDB via Terminal as given here: [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: If you're running `mongod` locally on that machine then what they have currently in db will work perfect as the URI would be `mongodb://localhost:27017/dashboard`

Comment: Thank you, at least my browser finds something now and even displays "DM Dashboard" in the title. But it's still an empty side, there should be a link to create a new account. But that's another problem, so thank you for helping me out! :)